# Can I download the blockchain, with a regular harddrive?

Tags: blockchain, download

Can I download the blockchain, with a regular harddrive? I don't have an SSD one. Is there away for me to download the block chain faster? Right now my Monerod says (69%, 846310 left). The net hash is 288.72 MH/s, v11, 12(out)+29(in)

I'm not going to download the blockchain, unless it will be ok with my type of hard drive. Here is a website that I read about downloading the blockchain. https://www.monero.how/tutorial-how-to-speed-up-initial-blockchain-sync

I have 16GB of RAM, and am using a laptop.

Comment: The link you refer to is poor advice. See the [official guide](https://www.getmonero.org/resources/user-guides/importing_blockchain.html) (and warning) on this method: "To use Monero, just start the software and it will synchronize itself with the peer-to-peer network. Normally, this is much faster than downloading and importing the blockchain as detailed in this guide"

Answer (score 1):

> Can I download the blockchain, with a regular harddrive?

Yes, but it will take considerably longer to sync than if you use a locally attached SSD.

However, once you've done the initial full sync, and if you plan on keeping it continuously online, there won't be any significant impact moving onwards.

Comment: Thanks for the reply jtgrassie. Do you know how much longer it would take with a regular harddrive? How long for an SSD? Right now it is at 785,320. And net hash 1.25 GH/s, v12, 14(out)+21. It has been up foe 6 hours. Fixing to turn the computer off in a few minutes.

Comment: An SSD usually just overnight, so less than a day. A HDD will probably (it's been years since I last synced to a HDD), take a week.

Comment: I started the Monerod on Dec. 19th. I was running it in Nov., but I closed it wrong, and had to reinstall the wallet. I might try the instructions in the link I posted, on Friday night .I will have to use command prompt for that. It is at 72%, 774715 left,  net hash 1.32 GH/s, v12, 12(out)+28(in)                                                                                      The wallet, and Monerod are showing two different numbers. Wallet says 1125500, while Monerod says 774715.

Comment: I went to the website, to download the raw blockchain. But it says it will take 22 hours, to 1 day to download. Unless I can pause the download, and download some more the next couple of days, I might just stop the download, and just keep using Monerod.  Can the download be paused, and restarted the next day? Here is where I got the download from.   https://www.getmonero.org/resources/user-guides/importing_blockchain.html

Comment: In almost all cases it's better to just sync the blockchain normally (i.e. not to download and import the raw file).

Comment: After downloading 53.4 GB, it stopped, and said download complete. Is there away to resume the download? If not, then I might just sync it normally.

Comment: The link you posted is poor advice as it suggests downloading the raw file will "speed up initial sync". In almost all cases it will be quicker and more reliable to just sync normally (which you can stop & resume perfectly safely).

Comment: I now have another problem. Windows updated today. Now when I click on Monerod, it opens up. But then a popup comes up, and it says Monerod has stopped working. Should I create another post for that, or is this the right place for this problem. I was at 525,000.

Comment: An update. I have a Bitcoin wallet called Electrum. So I did a search. Are there Monero wallets that are like Electrum. I found one, and it is called MyMonero. I don't have to download any blocks. It is light, and easy to use.